# How much time do Canadian authorities give to non-Canadians to drive from the southern US-Canadian border to Alaska?

Tags: usa, canada, driving, covid-19, alaska

I read on https://www.alaskapublic.org/2020/07/30/the-rules-for-crossing-the-canadian-border-into-alaska-just-got-even-stricter:

> Travelers will be given a tag to hang from their rearview mirrors for the duration of their trip to or from Alaska. The tags are intended to show that travelers are transiting and **include the date they must depart Canada**.

How much time do Canadian authorities give to non-Canadians to drive from the southern US-Canadian border to Alaska?

Comment: The official government statement at https://www.canada.ca/en/border-services-agency/news/2020/07/covid-19-stricter-rules-for-foreign-nationals-transiting-through-canada-to-alaska.html only says "a reasonable period of stay".  It may be at the discretion of the border officer, perhaps depending on any special circumstances stated by the traveler.  I don't know if that is an answer or not.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks, that's a great answer (you're welcome to convert your comment into an answer), but hopefully someone will some experience with it will share to us how much time they got so that we have a sense of it. 2 days? 1 week? Maybe that depends on whether we show up with a tractor or a lambo.

Comment: According to this news report  https://www.npr.org/2020/08/25/905847150/american-man-accused-of-breaking-canadas-covid-19-rules-faces-560-000-fine travellers are meant to take ‘the most direct route’. So the answer may vary depending on the entry point and destination, I’d imagine

Comment: People keep the comments to the point, asking extra information is alright but do keep it to facts only and do not assume what OP will do with their time.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.